# Combining routes in Compojure

Tags: clojure, compojure

I have two different web applications in Clojure developed with Compojure. Each use defroutes to create its handler.

How can I combine the two different definitions of defroutes into one defroute? I want to reuse the routes of the first app into the second.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [compojure.core/routes](https://weavejester.github.io/compojure/compojure.core.html#var-routes) to combine routes:

```
 (def my-handler
    (routes some-handler
            some-other-handler))
```

Comment: I tried   


    (def route1 [(GET "/" [] (index-page))
    (route/resources "/") (route/not-found "Page not found")]) 
    (def allroutes (concat routes1 routes2)) 
    (def app (handler/site (apply routes allroutes)))  

But the second routes are not used

Comment: Ok I found the error: one need to take care of not having a route-not-found handler in the first list...

Comment: "Ok I found the error: one need to take care of not having a route-not-found handler in the first list... –" please elaborate? what solution did you discover?

Comment: Maybe it's kinda late, but I think the point was that the `not-found` route should be last in the list of routes, otherwise it will match all the url and the app will always return "Not Found"