# Clojure - combine pedestal routes

Tags: clojure, pedestal

How do I combine routes in Pedestal ?

```
(defroutes api-routes [...])
(defroutes site-routes [...])
(combine-routes api-routes site-routes) ;; should be a valid route as well
```

Note : This is a similar question as [Combining routes in Compojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329173/combining-routes-in-compojure), but for Pedestal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as easy as

```
(def all-routes (concat api-routes site-routes))
```

The explanation starts from here https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/master/guides/documentation/service-routing.md#defining-route-tables, it is stated that

> A route table is simply a data structure; in our case, it is a sequence of maps.

pedestal team calls that *sequence of maps* route table form as **verbose format** and they design a **terse format** of route table which is what we supply to `defroute`. The `defroute` then transform our terse format to the verbose format.

You can check for yourself in the repl

```
;; here we supply a terse route format to defroutes
> (defroutes routes
  [[["/" {:get home-page}
     ["/hello" {:get hello-world}]]]]) 
;;=> #'routes

;; then we pretty print the verbose route format
> (pprint routes)
;;=>
({:path-parts [""],
  :path-params [],
  :interceptors
  [{:name :mavbozo-pedestal.core/home-page,
    :enter
    #object[io.pedestal.interceptor$eval7317$fn__7318$fn__7319 0x95d91f4 "io.pedestal.interceptor$eval7317$fn__7318$fn__7319@95d91f4"],
    :leave nil,
    :error nil}],
  :path "/",
  :method :get,
  :path-re #"/\Q\E",
  :route-name :mavbozo-pedestal.core/home-page}
 {:path-parts ["" "hello"],
  :path-params [],
  :interceptors
  [{:name :mavbozo-pedestal.core/hello-world,
    :enter
    #object[io.pedestal.interceptor$eval7317$fn__7318$fn__7319 0x4a168461 "io.pedestal.interceptor$eval7317$fn__7318$fn__7319@4a168461"],
    :leave nil,
    :error nil}],
  :path "/hello",
  :method :get,
  :path-re #"/\Qhello\E",
  :route-name :mavbozo-pedestal.core/hello-world})
```

So, because pedestal route is just a sequence of maps, we can easily combine multiple non-overlapping routes with `concat`.

That is what I like about one of clojure's principles which pedestal team follows: **generic data manipulation** which in this case, a verbose formatted route table is just a map--a ordinary clojure's data structure which can be inspected and manipulated with regular clojure.core's data structure manipulation functions such as `concat`. Even the terse format is also a plain clojure data structure and can easily inspected and manipulated with the same means.